# Can I use this Ikea glassware on stove top?

Tags: cookware, stove, glass

In particular, this [VARDAGEN Glass Bowl](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/70289248/).

It's almost a quarter inch thick, feels heavy and solid, wonder if anyone has tried.  Nothing fancy, just boil and soup kind of thing.  I figure it's healthier than stainless steel.  Thought?

Comment: The page you link to says 'WARNING - Serious or fatal crashing injuries can occur from furniture tip-over. To prevent this furniture must be permanently fixed to the wall.'. Is your stove close enough to a wall :-)

Comment: Must be one of those tub-ready toaster ...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, you can't.

You should always assume glass is not safe to use on the stovetop. Essentially none of it is, and while there are a very few exceptions, they'll say so explicitly. (For example [this set](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008XWSAZ4) says stovetop-safe in the description.)

That bowl is nothing special, definitely not stovetop-safe - it'd shatter under the thermal stress. If you look carefully on the packaging, you might even find a warning that's *not* for use on the stovetop.

Comment: Thanks, you made it crystal clear.  I know the Vision, just not a big fan of the color.  The only other one explicit for cooking costs $200.  Since it's  made by MoMA, I wasn't sure if it meant to be artwork or cookware.

Comment: In general, if it doesn't specifically say "stovetop safe", "oven safe", or "broiler safe", it's not safe to use it as anything other than a bowl.

Comment: MoMA Art installation: "A Chef who didn't bother reading the labels: The Consequences"

Comment: Visions is not glass, from what I recall when they were first marketing it (I have some.) Visions is "transparent ceramic."

Comment: @Ecnerwal The description on Amazon says glass-ceramic. In any case it's still the exception.

Comment: @Ecnerwal That sounds like spin off transparent aluminum from Star Trek.  I thought aluminum is not safe for cooking?  Or it's like those lead glass is not really poisonous lead thing.

Comment: @Whoever aluminum is definitely safe for cooking