# Can I reheat meal in pyrex-like glassware on vitro ceramic stove?

Tags: stove, kitchen-safety, glass

I have this delicious dish with gravy I did yesterday, and the rest is still in the pyrex-like oven proof glassware used to cook it.

Can I "cheat" and quickly reheat directly on my vitro ceramic stove top ? That would seem much quicker than reheating it the oven, and would save dish washing compared to transfering the contents into a frying pan.

My core question is specifically about the integrity of the glassware (though I'm aware it should reheat less uniformly than in the oven).

There is a [related question that I found](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/70944/can-i-use-this-ikea-glassware-on-stove-top), but it is about a bowl that was not especially made for the oven at all, so I guess this question is different.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would **absolutely** not recommend heating Pyrex with any type of direct heat, ever.

That stuff goes off like a hand-grenade, highly dangerous - not to mention messy.

I've seen it happen too many times for it to be even vaguely worth the risk; even when accidentally placed on recently switched-off hobs.

Pyrex is a low-expansion glass. However, low-expansion does not mean zero-expansion, so if the bottom is being heated whilst the top stays cool, the expansion difference is enough to cause it to simply explode all over the kitchen.

Yes to microwave, but a solid no for a hob.
[& I'm talking UK Pyrex, I didn't know US was even worse until I read the [Pyrex wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrex) ChrisH posted]

If you have no microwave, then either oven or transfer it to a pan.
The extra washing up is safer & far less hassle than trying to clean the hob, then find all the *really really* sharp glass shards that will find every corner of a 20m square room.

Comment: Agreed! Bad bad bad idea!

Comment: Very interesting. My mom used to make pop corn in a Flame Resistant Pyrex pan when I was a kid (in europe), and I always thought all Pyrex products were the same... glad I learned this today

Comment: There's "Visions" also by Corning, which is a stove-top 'glass' pan range. The two should never be confused. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visions_(cookware)

Comment: I tried using Visions stuff a few years back, I was not impressed. The see through is a novelty that isn't that handy, and the pots aren't really a joy to cook with.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, [it makes a difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrex) where you are.  American "pyrex" would be very likely to break, while European "PYREX" would have a good chance if heated gently.  However I wouldn't recommend it even then. If you've got a microwave that would do a better job of reheating than the stove top and either sort of Pyrex can generally take microwaving

Comment: Indeed a microwave would be an obvious better alternative for reheating, but I don't have one.